# Selenium - using csv as dataframe - inputting user data on a website (onboarding) - need help iterating through the whole csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, selenium-webdriver

```
    import pandas as pd
    import time
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


    df = pd.read_csv('testfile.csv')
    details_lst = []
    for column in df.columns:
        details_lst.append(df[column][0])


    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('xxxxxxx')
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_phM_phB_Username").send_keys('xxxxx')
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_phM_phB_Password").send_keys('xxxxxx')
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_phM_phB_LoginButton").click()
    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Administration").click()
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_phM_phB_UserAdministrationUserControl_CreateNewUserButton").click()
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_phM_phB_txtFirstName").send_keys(df['firstname'][0])
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_phM_phB_txtLastName").send_keys(df['lastname'][0])
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_phM_phB_txtEmail").send_keys(df['username'][0])
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_phM_phB_txtNotificationEmail").send_keys(df['email'][0])
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_phM_phB_txtVerifyNotificationEmail").send_keys(df['email'][0])
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_phM_phB_txtPhone").send_keys(df['phone'][0])
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnNext").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "chkOrderProducts").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_phM_phB_AccountNumbersList1_lstAvailableAcctNumbers").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_phM_phB_AccountNumbersList1_lstAvailableAcctNumbers").send_keys(Keys.ARROW_UP)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_phM_phB_AccountNumbersList1_lstAvailableAcctNumbers").send_keys(Keys.TAB)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_phM_phB_AccountNumbersList1_btnAddAccount").send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
```

I know the code is a bit sloppy, but it get's the job done on the website im using. I am able to run through the first row of my csv just fine.

What im doing is logging into a vendor website - and im inputting user data from a csv into the website using keyboard shortcuts to navigate. The script works, but it only goes through the first row -I want it to go through all of the rows.  it seems i need to write a for loop to iterate through the rows until there is a null cell?

https://imgur.com/HVBHnVO

I am able to run through row 2 sucessfully - but i am at a loss for how to iterate to the next row.

I am able to run through the first row of my csv, and the account is created just fine. I have my script setup so it is ready to input the next row - i just don't understand to write the necessary loop to iterate to the next row - any help is appreciated, i have been typing away for hours trying to figure this out - i am 90% there - just need some assistance.

Comment: are you trying to create multiple accounts using selenium? why not just add directly to database?

Comment: @DanielSabrel Yes, I have a csv where I want to add multiple new users. My script is able to go through the 2nd row of my CSV and creates the account just fine - just need to go through the rest of my csv. 

It's an older website, only way to add accounts is the site - there unfortunately is no database access.

Comment: Cleaned up the unecesarry part of the code as it might just confuse people as was too verbose. The code works 90% just need to figure out how to go through the other rows in my csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through df.

```
...
for row_num in range(df.shape[0]):
    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Administration").click()
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_phM_phB_UserAdministrationUserControl_CreateNewUserButton").click()
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ctl00_phM_phB_txtFirstName").send_keys(df['firstname'][row_num])    # row_num here
...
```

Comment: So I placed it on the bottom of my script since when I put it where you suggested the script kept on restarting too early and never completing the task. 

What is weird is that is looping now with it on the bottom, but it will only loop on the [row_num] on the sheet over and over without going to the next row.  Given my example sheet https://imgur.com/HVBHnVO - say if i use row 0, it will loop test User over and over without going to testUser2 - any ideas - appreaciate the help i'm about 98% of the way now

Comment: can you try running this in different py file: `import pandas as pd`, `df = pd.read_csv('testfile.csv')`,`for row_num in range(df.shape[0]): print(df['firstname'][row_num])`

Comment: You can use [Selenium WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) to wait till elements load in browser

Comment: NVM you are a legend - got it sorted out thanks to you - I was writing out the row# instead of using the for you used of row_num. 

Thanks again.